# Concatenated diagonalization of combined real/imaginary diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

I have a problem involving a complex matrix that I need to diagonalize and apply weights to the entries according to a function relating only to the eigenvalues of the real part of the matrix.

Suppose that I have diagonalized separately the real and imaginary parts of $ A=A_r+iA_i $ such that: $ A_r=U_r\Lambda_rU_r^{-1} $ and $ A_i=U_i\Lambda_iU_i^{-1} $. What I need to do next is calculate a weighted "error" norm which, given two complex vectors $ x,\ y $ is written as:

$ \sum_{i=1}^N w_i|y-Ax|_i^2 $
and $ A=U_r\Lambda_rU_r^{-1}+iU_i\Lambda_iU_i^{-1}  $

I then rewrite the problem as:

$ \begin{bmatrix} y_r \newline y_i \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} A_r & -A_i \newline A_i & A_r \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_r \newline x_i \end{bmatrix} $

I thought that to correctly apply weights to my rows, I would first need to find a new $ 2N\times 2N $ orthogonal matrix $ U $ such that $ \tilde{y}=U^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} y_r \newline y_i \end{bmatrix},\ \tilde{x}=U^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} x_r \newline x_i \end{bmatrix} $ and $ \sum w_i|y-Ax|_i^2 = \sum w_i|\tilde{y}-\Lambda\tilde{x}|_i^2 $

where $ \Lambda $ would be a new diagonal matrix* and then I could correctly apply the weights to my rows according to some function of the $ [\Lambda_r]_{ii} $ for each $ i $. Essentially, is there any way to find a new diagonalization $ U,\ \Lambda $ such that:

$ \begin{bmatrix} U_r\Lambda_r U_r^{-1} & -U_i\Lambda_i U_i^{-1} \newline U_i\Lambda_i U_i^{-1} & U_r\Lambda_r U_r^{-1} \end{bmatrix} = U\Lambda U^{-1} $

Thanks for your inputs in advance!

*(possibly $ \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_r & 0 \newline 0 & \Lambda_i \end{bmatrix} $ ?)

Comment: @Vincent: that doesn't work. You would need $U$ to be real and this is not guaranteed. And note that if the real and imaginary parts were simultaneously diagonalizable then in particular they would have to commute, which is also not guaranteed.

Comment: O wait, you are right. Sorry, I'll withdraw my comment

Comment: Thanks, that'd be a special case I think.. it might be solved analytically but oh I wrote down the equations and sighed; it looks more like things would cancel out or that it might be corollary of some theorem